# PHP send mail works in command line but not PHP file

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, smtp, sendmail

I set up SMTP to email, and when using the command line to send emails, this works perfectly fine.  However, I wrote this simple code to test from a PHP file, and it neither works when loading from a browser, nor when running `php mail.php` from command line.  Here's the simple code:

```
<?php
if(mail("user@gmail.com","Testing PHP","Hope this works!"))
    print "Email successful";
else
    print "Failure";
?>
```

When I do run `php mail.php` I get a

```
Authorization Failed (xxxx Too Many Login Attemps, please try again later)
```

message... which confuses me because it passes authorization when just using the command line function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are saying something weird: how can you get a message "Authorization Failed", when mail function is not logining anywhere? Please, remove any other code from the file and run pure mail function.

Comment: I only meant that when running the above file in a browser using apache, I do receive the "Failure" message as described in the code above, so I decided to try to run the code line "php mail.php" (the name of my php file) in the hopes of getting some sort of helpful error message.  The error message that resulted was the one concerning Authentication failed, given right there in the command line.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I suspect, something is wrong with sendmail or postfix on your server. Did you contact the hosting support?

Comment: I'm actually using an ec2 instance (student project).  I guess I just keep coming back to why would it pass authentication using the linux command line msmtp, but the mail function does not?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your distribution. E.g. on Debian there are separated configs for CLI (command line) and webserver php (also depends how you run php scripts cgi, fpm, etc.).

In config `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` you might be interested in `mail function` part:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path = sendmail -t -i
```

Make sure you have configured your SMTP correctly, you can test it from console:

```
php -r 'mail("test@example.com","Testing php -v ".phpversion(),"php on ".gethostname());'
```